# C# performance of basic operations

Tags: c#, performance-testing

I have found several articles (including some questions in SA), trying to find the cost of basic operations.

However, i tried to make my own little program, so that i could test it myself. When trying to test addition and subtraction i encountered something, that i present you in simple code

```
       int a,i,j;
        DateTime d1,d2;

        a = 0;
        d1= DateTime.Now;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 10000; j++)
            a = a + 1;
        d2=DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("a=a+1\t1E8\t"+(d2-d1));

        a = 0;
        d1 = DateTime.Now;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 10000; j++)
                a = a + 1;
        d2 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("a=a+1\t1E8\t" + (d2 - d1));

        a = 0;
        d1 = DateTime.Now;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 10000; j++)
                a = a + 1;
        d2 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("a=a+1\t1E8\t" + (d2 - d1));

        a = 0;
        d1 = DateTime.Now;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 10000; j++)
                a = a + 1;
        d2 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("a=a+1\t1E8\t" + (d2 - d1));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

First i declare some variables and then i perform the same task 4 times.
every single time i do the exact same thing.
Always , the result is the following:

```
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2300230
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2180218
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2130213
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2150215
```

or

```
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2340000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2170000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2130000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2100000
```

meaning that the first time, it ALWAYS takes longer to compute (about 5% longer). All the other times, the time is about the same.

Then i just add the line `a=0;` after the first `a=0;`. The result is as follows:

```
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2210000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2170000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2200000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2170000
```

or even

```
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2160000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2160000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2200000
a=a+1   1E8     00:00:00.2230000
```

So 3 questions:

1. Why is the first loop take longer than the rest in the first example?
2. Why all the loops take about same time in the second example?
3. Is there any better way to compute time interval than `Datetime`

Personal POV:
Something needs to be initialized when the program starts running. By adding an extra command (a=0), i give the program the time to make its initializations.

Flaw in POV: 
When i change the number of loops from 10^8 to 10^9, the difference between time1 and time2 should again be ~0.015s(if my POV was valid). but now it is again ~0.15s (meaning again ~5%). If i add the second `a=0`, then again time1~time2~time3~time4

Comment: You should really read Eric Lippert's blog posts about benchmark errors: http://ericlippert.com/tag/benchmarks/

Comment: The JIT compiler.. Jon's link (Eric's post) is a fantastic read. What you should take away from it, if nothing else, is "Treat the first run as nothing special when measuring average performance".

Comment: The "cost of an operation" may very well depend on the operations before and after it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead why is JIT an issue here? there should not be JIT compilation during his measures.

Comment: It could be anything. Trying to make any assumptions from results differing by small fractions of seconds benchmarked by DateTime.Now is ridiculous in itself.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question number 3 - 
**Is there any better way to compute time interval than Datetime?**

Use **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch** for measuring time difference as it gives very high accuracy.